# Actionscript 2 : Split() , Join()

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

My Question is how would i turn a string from this

```
"Hello"
```

to this

```
"H" + "e" + "l" + "l" + "o"
```

in Actionscript 2.. So far i've created 3 functions which after they are ran
my string returns as

```
H + e + l + l + o
```

The Problem im having is the letters arent considered Strings.. what can i do ?

Here is my code

```
function doURL(Link:String){
    var Splitted:String = SplitURL(Link);
    var Joined:String = JoinURL(Splitted);
    var Product:String = Joined;
    return Product;
}

function SplitURL(Link:String){
    var SplitLink:Array = Link.split("");
    var realLink:String = SplitLink;
    return realLink;
}

function JoinURL(Split:Array){
    var JoinLink:String = Split.join(" + ");
    return JoinLink;
}
```

Im a little confused on how to add the extra quotations into the outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape quotes in a string with backslash.

```
var s:String = "Hello";
var a:Array = s.split("");
trace("\"" + a.join("\" + \"") + "\"");
```

Result :

```
"H" + "e" + "l" + "l" + "o"
```